# How to clear cache in Opencart from PHP

Tags: php, caching, opencart, server, vqmod

I need to clear cache on certain condition from PHP code. How can I do so. I know that there is object Cache exists in opencart engine, but how do delete cache correctly.
Or it is possible to delete just folders ?
Please give advice.

Answer (score 8):

In OpenCart there are 3 places that store cache

1. image cache is located at `public_html/image/cache`
2. if you have vQmod `public_html/vqmod/vqcache`
3. system (data) cache `public_html/system/cache`

You can delete files within these folders - do not delete the `cache` folders - only the content inside.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to take a look at some models in `admin` folder and check some add/delete methods, i.e. in `admin/model/catalog/product.php` the `addProduct()` method calls:

```
$this->cache->delete('product');
```

where `'product'` is the key defining which *cache* to delete. Other keys might be `category`, `language`, `currency`, etc.

Comment: Your solution fails. For ex.: you replace primary product image, but preserve its name. Clearing cache with `$this->cache->delete('product')` doesn't affect on image cache - image still would be served with old img.

Comment: @userlond OP wasn't asking about image cache which is in your browser BTW. In all modern browsers, hitting CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE will open a window/page, where you can delete your browser cache - but this has nothing to do with OpenCart (i.e. your comment is completely OT).

Comment: Just for clarifying. I changed image of product  with my own code, but preserved name of image (calling $this->cache->delete('product') was made). OC 2.0 still served old image from `image/cache` folder. I.e. clearing `image/cache` helped me... So it's nice addon to your answer.

Comment: Noty about browser caching is also useful in some situations

Answer (score 0):

It works to me-
Go to: 
Step 1.
In admin dashboard click in `Dashboard` and you will get `gearing icon` in top right side and click on it. You get see `Developer Settings`. And you get find `Cache` and `Action`. So, in Cache click on `Off` and Click `Refresh Icon` in Action.
Step 2. 
 `Admin > Extensions > Modifications >` 
click on the `Refresh Icon` that you will see in top right side and check again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it manually or by clearing cache folder files by php script.

If you are using other than 3.X version then the cache folder is in : System > storage > cache

If its a 3.X version then got to storage folder wherever you have moved that then inside that folder there is a cache folder.

Clear cache folder data & reload your store page. This solution worked for me. Thanks for asking this question.